# discord js problem: I have a horse race command and Im trying to make it so only people with certain permissions can call the command

Tags: javascript

I dont even know where to start adding the perms. I have tried so many options and a syntax error comes back every time. The command works perfectly. I just want it limited to who can use it like adminstrator or manage_permissions. any advice on where to start or what to do would greatly be appreciated. I really am at a loss on what to do.

```
const status = require('./../util/status');

function startRace(message, args) {
    const trackLength = 50;
    const initialHorseDistance = 100;
    const numberOfHorses = 6;
    const horseNames = ["Athemir", "Rildonis", "Hyrget", "Maldonar", "Zael", "Getha"];

    status.racing.initalise(horseNames);

    message.channel.send("Our participants are:\n" + horseNames.map((horseName, i) => {return `${i + 1}: ${horseName}`}).join('\n') );

    let horseDistances = Array(numberOfHorses).fill(initialHorseDistance);
    raceTrack = renderRaceTrack(horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance);

    const bettingReactions = ["\u0030\u20E3", "\u0031\u20E3", "\u0032\u20E3", "\u0033\u20E3", "\u0034\u20E3", "\u0035\u20E3", "\u0036\u20E3", "\u0037\u20E3", "\u0038\u20E3", "\u0039\u20E3"];

    message.channel.send("Bettings open for 10 minutes, place bets now.").then(
        async message => {
            // const emoji = message.guild.emojis.find('name', 'one');
            await message.react(bettingReactions[1]);
            await message.react(bettingReactions[2]);
            await message.react(bettingReactions[3]);
            await message.react(bettingReactions[4]);
            await message.react(bettingReactions[5]);
            await message.react(bettingReactions[6]);

            // bettingReactions.forEach(async reaction => {await message.react(reaction)} );
        }
    ).then(() => {
        const filter = (receivedReaction) => bettingReactions.includes(receivedReaction);
        message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 600000 })
            .then(collected => {
                console.log(collected[0]);
            })
            .then(()=> {
                message.channel.send("Bets received, starting race.");
                message.channel.send(raceTrack).then(message => { createNextFrame(message, horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance, 0) });
            })
    });
}

function createNextFrame(message, horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance, n) {
    let winners = [];
    horseDistances.forEach((length, horse_index) => {
        length = length - Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
        horseDistances[horse_index] = length;
        if (length <= 0) winners.push(horse_index);
    });
    console.log(n);
    console.log(horseDistances);
    if (winners.length > 0) {
        message.edit(renderRaceTrack(horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance));
        return declareWinner(message, winners);
    }

    message.edit(renderRaceTrack(horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance)).then(message => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            createNextFrame(message, horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance, n + 1);
        }, 1000);
    })
}

function declareWinner(message, winners) {
    console.log("Winner declared!")
    if (winners.length === 1)
        message.channel.send(`Horse ${winners[0]+1} has WON!`);
    else
        message.channel.send(`There has been a draw between horses ${winners[0]+1} and ${winners[0]+1}`);
}

function renderRaceTrack(horseDistances, trackLength, initialHorseDistance) {
    const horse = '<:centaurracer:874074443184500847>';
    const finish = ':checkered_flag:';
    const trackSeperator = '-';
    const bar = '|';
    const lane = '`' + trackSeperator.repeat(trackLength) + '`' + '\n';
    let raceTrack = lane;
    for (i = 0; i < horseDistances.length; i++) {
        currentHorseDistance = horseDistances[i] < 0 ? 0 : horseDistances[i];
        raceTrack = raceTrack + finish + bar + ' '.repeat(currentHorseDistance) + horse + ' '.repeat(initialHorseDistance - currentHorseDistance) + bar + ' ' + bar + ' ' + (i + 1) + '\n' + lane;
    }
    return raceTrack;

}

module.exports = {
    name: 'horse',
    description: 'Starts a race, with default number of horses, and default length unless otherwise specified.',
    args: 'false',
    execute: startRace
    }
```

This was my latest try

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("^horse")) {
      if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js v12:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Define Discord
const client = new Discord.client(); // Define client

client.login('your-discord-token'); // Login your bot
let prefix = "^"; // Define prefix

client.on("message", async (message) => { // Setup a message event listener
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "horse")) { // If the message content matches the command
        // Define member
        let member =  client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).members.cache.get(message.author.id);
        if (!member.hasPermissions("ADMINISTRATOR")) return; // Check if the member has administrator privileges
    }
});
```

Discord.js v13:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Define Discord
const client = new Discord.client({ // Define client
   intents: ['GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD'] // Add client intents
});

client.login('your-discord-token'); // Login your bot
let prefix = "^"; // Define prefix

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => { // Setup event listener
    if (message.data && !message.author) return; // Make sure the command wasn't a slash command or button click
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "horse")) { // Check the message content contains the command
        // Find the guild then the member that sent the message
        let member = (await client.guilds.fetch(message.guild_id || message.guild.id)).members.cache.get(message.author ? message.author.id : message.member.user.id);
        if (!member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return; // Check if the guild member has administrator privileges
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this. The bot has a music bot integrated too. So, it comes back with 
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Define Discord
const client = new Discord.client({ // Define client

these already being declared

Comment: @Seamus If the variables have already been declared then you can remove them.